# How does the model respond to the method :find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to get used to Rails and Ruby for the last two months and I`ve got a small question that stuck in my mind in order to be able to see the bigger picture more clearly.

Let`s assume I have a model named Playlist and I already have some entries in my database:

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

As far as I understand we can reach a model instance which should correspond to a raw in database via the following:

```
p = Playlist.find(2)
```

First, the result "p" is an instance of the model Playlist, right? Second, I am trying to understand where the ":find" method is implemented or how the model responds to it. Is it a class method for my model or a class method for ActiveRecord::Base? Because I couldn`t list ":find" in any of the outputs below.

```
puts p.class.methods(false).sort
puts p.class.superclass.methods(false).sort
puts p.class.superclass.superclass.methods(false).sort
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have Rails installed, so I can't show you what the output would be, but the easiest way would be to just ask the method itself where it is defined: `meth = Playlist.method(:find); p meth.owner, meth.source_location`

Answer (score 0):

It's a class method of Playlist that it has inherited from ActiveRecord::Base.

Try:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.methods
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb

Comment: I think the OP's question is really trying to pinpoint which class it's directly defined in. A call to `.methods` shows inherited as well as directly defined methods (and `Playlist.methods` also therefore shows `:find`). If you call, `ActiveRecord::Base.methods(false)` (which should give the class methods that aren't inherited), then `:find` doesn't show up. If you chase this up the short parentage of classes, none of the parent classes show `:find` when you call, `.methods(false)`.

Comment: @lurker yes I see what you mean. I suppose that technically then, `find` is an instance method of the FinderMethods module of ActiveRecord. `ActiveRecord::FinderMethods.instance_methods(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the Classes and/or Modules containing the `:find` method:

```
x = Playlist.ancestors
arr = []
m = :find

x.each{ |i| arr << i if i.method_defined?(m) }

puts "The following Classes and/or Modules contain the :#{m.to_s} method:"
puts arr
```

The first printed result is where the method m is located. The results below it list the ancestor Class and/or Modules (in order) containing the 'original' method before modification (although they may contain different methods entirely using the same method-name). This may come in handy if you want to investigate the relevant method further.

N.B. Only public and protected methods are matched using the `method_defined?` method.